# Namespace Tuple could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tuples

I want to make a tuple in Unity to store a string and two `Vector3's.` However, for some reason my C# doesn't want to make tuples. I get the IDE error:
The type or namespace 'Tuple' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? [Assembly-Csharp]
Here is the code:

```
public class PuzzleVars : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject FENbuilder;
// will be calling the FENbuild function from here
public Tuple<string, Vector3, Vector3> forkPuzzles = new Tuple<string, Vector3, Vector3>();
```

Comment: The `Tuple` class is part of the `System` namespace. Do you have a `using System;` line at the start of your code?

Comment: There's also [value tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) built into C# 7+ which are essentially structs, great for when you don't want to use reference types.

Answer (score 0):

Tuple requires the System import.

Add `using System;` above your class declaration and your code should work fine.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class PuzzleVars : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject FENbuilder;
    // will be calling the FENbuild function from here
    public Tuple<string, Vector3, Vector3> forkPuzzles = new Tuple<string, Vector3, Vector3>();
}
```

### Side note for future issues

Unity recommends that you use Visual Studio as your default code editor. This makes sense, as with Visual Studio, when you see an issue such as this, you only need to right click the erroneous code then left click "Quick actions and refactoring" and 9 times out of 10, left clicking the top option will solve your errors.